# How to search this on Google?

Tags: google-search

It's a little meta...

.. But how do I "properly" search for something like `Visual C++ Executable Stack` on Google?
(See below for an illustration of the problem.)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"? Note that not everyone can see your image, but even so, what are the results you're expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reached an edge case, there is not much you can do other than exclude Stack Overflow from the search `-site:`. Search all other sites and then search with Stack Overflow instead. No combination of searches can help this.

Answer (score 0):

There are no right or wrong answers here - the quality of the search results is subjective. However, you can choose to follow some tips available in search guides (like [this one](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861) from Google):

1. **Phrase search ("")** - wrap an exact phrases with double quotes (e.g., `Visual C++ "Executable Stack"`)
2. **Search single word exactly as is ("")** - double quotes around a single word to avoid synonyms
3. **Search within a specific website (site:)** - restrict searches to one site (e.g., `Visual C++ "Executable Stack" site:msdn.com`)
4. **Terms you want to exclude (-)** - you can remove "Overflow"  (e.g., `Visual C++ "Executable Stack" -overflow`)

There are other examples in the guide if you're interested in further refining your search results.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Just a note though: I can't really exclude "overflow", because then that would mean I wouldn't get results from Stack Overflow, which is not what I want...

Comment: Understood - just using it as an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit unclear, but I don't see any problems with the results. If you're using double quotes (`"`) Google will include that term as is. Except there are other symbols in between if the query contains more than one word.

Comment: The trouble is that `Executable Stack` is matching `... executable? - Stack Overflow` even though the topic is pretty irrelevant :\